# My dropdown menus are showing up under the same top element

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, wordpress-theming

See website - http://webbetasite.com/dahlberg/

as you can see my dropdown menus aren't showing up properly under its parent.

please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position:relative` to

`#header .container #top-menu ul.top-menu li`

So that the dropdowns open relative to the `parent` menu item, and not `relative` to `top-menu` - as is the case now.

Comment: Thank you very much - that totally fixed it! Thanks Nick

Answer (score -1):

You could position each sub-menu at a fixed distance from left.
Give each sub-menu item an id and set a css directive on this.
Example:

```
<li class="sub-menu" id="sub1">Entry</li>
```

Css:

```
#sub1 {left:120px;}
```